# ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, rman

I am executing a stored procedure in order to perform some nightly maintenance on the database.
Which is Oracle 11.2.0.3.0.

The procedure uses RMAN to perform a daily backup, the backup finishes but I get the error:

`ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited`

This causes the backup to be restarted and the stored procedure enters a loop state.

This procedure runs a several other machines without any issues.
I've checked Oracle trace logs but no error where recorded there.

What can be the cause of this?
Please assist.

Comment: Can we see some of the code in the procedure? Or the entire code? Can you upload it to pastebin?

Comment: @mmmmmpie
Due to security reasons I cannot post the code.
Are there any general suggestions of what might cause this?
Note that this happens only on one machine, on others it work without issues.

Comment: Sanitize the code? Could this be a permissions issue? Is it possible that the executing schema doesn't have dbms_java execute? [source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_29532_java_call_terminated_by_uncaught_java_exception_string.htm) Also make sure that the schema has appropriate UTL permissions.

Comment: @mmmmmpie
I will check UTL permissions, thanks !